# Proper way to cancel all waiting pushes or pops on tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I am using a tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue to communicate in a buffered fashion between N producer/consumer threads.

Like so:

```
//which has been set to some max capacity
tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<MyItemType> g_queue; 

ThreadA()
{ 
  while(running_A)
  { 
    MyItemType outItem;
    //do some stuff, resulting in filling outItem ...
    g_queue.push(outItem);
  }
}

ThreadB()
{
  while(running_B)
  { 
    MyItemType inItem;
    g_queue.pop(inItem);
    //do some stuff with the contents of inItem
  }
}
```

The example I just showed only has one producer and one consumer, in reality there can many of both. At a user's request all processing should cease as soon as possible.

So if thread A has pushed a few items, that B had not consumed, I want the next call to B's pop to immediately return somehow indicating that the queue is closed so that I can break from the loop. Any items on the queue not serviced yet can be discarded.

If thread A is waiting on a push, I want that to return immediately, perhaps indicating that the queue is closed for business.

I read some where a way of potentially doing this is to push a special item (stop item, indicator of cease and desist) on the queue, then when that item is popped i can know things are stopping. The issue with this is that it's a FIFO queue, and any items ahead of the stop item need to be popped before it can get to my stop item. Which i want to avoid.

I see there is an q.abort method, that would cause waiting push or pops to return throwing an exception (works only if I set a tbb preprocessor define TBB_USE_EXCEPTIONS). Didn't think having to turn on exceptions for all of tbb to be a proper way of doing this?

I also thought I could clear the queue before adding my stop item, but theoretically another producer can come in between my current consumers q.clear() and q.push(stopItem), and push a non-stopItem, which is not what I want. Since i would have to wait for that non-stopItem to be processed before it can get to the pushed stopItem.

What is the proper way of handling this? I previously had my own queue implementation that had a close signal that would cause all pops and pushes to return (not just fill in the reference item parameter, but return a code from the function all) with a certain value code that would indicate that the queue was closed. Not sure how to have a similar capability with tbb's concurrent bounded queue.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
-Ryan

Comment: So, does my answer work for you?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you ask how to terminate producer&consumer at any random moment without processing remaining elements. If so, you need a separate notification mechanism, e.g. a flag:

```
tbb::atomic<bool> is_finished = false;
```

Then, you can read the flag in the loops in order to terminate them if not blocked:

```
ThreadA()
{ 
  while(running_A && !is_finished)
  { 
    MyItemType outItem;
    //do some stuff, resulting in filling outItem ...
    try { g_queue.push(outItem); } catch(...) {}
  }
}

ThreadB()
{
  while(running_B && !is_finished)
  { 
    MyItemType inItem;
    try { g_queue.pop(inItem); } catch(...) {}
    if(is_finished) // check before processing
        break;
    //do some stuff with the contents of inItem
  }
}

Terminate()
{
    is_finished = true;
    g_queue.abort();
}
```

If a thread is blocked, `abort()` looks like a fine way unless it needs to be done fast and repeatedly. `TBB_USE_EXCEPTIONS` is turned on by default in TBB binaries, so, you don't actually pay for it in TBB scheduler and conurrent_bounded_queue internals. And `TBB_USE_EXCEPTIONS` is turned on by default in TBB headers if application is compiled with enabled exceptions (often true). So you likely to pay only for try/catch block around push&pop.

There are alternatives to the exception. The most straightforward one is to unblock the threads by popping some items to unblock the producers and pushing a dummy item to unblock the consumers. E.g.:

```
Terminate()
{
    is_finished = true;
    MyItemType dummyItem;
    while(g_queue.size() < 0) // consumers are blocked
        g_queue.try_push(dummyItem);
    while(g_queue.size() >= g_queue.capacity() ) // producers are blocked
        g_queue.try_pop(dummyItem);
}
```

Comment: `Terminate` will fail if it is called after the loop check, but before the `pop` call, when `abort` has no effect.

Comment: It was so long time ago, so i don't understand your concern, which loop check? If you have a suggestion how to modify the answer, please be more specific

Comment: The `while` loop. Started my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182231/how-to-use-tbbs-concurrent-bounded-concurrent-queue-abort-correctly

Comment: I probably see what you mean. Both terminate versions are racy since the flag setting and the following queue operation are not atomic of course. Introducing another counter for number of active consumer and producer threads and running  terminate in a loop until there is no active threads will help